# Reduce padding between navigation icon and logo on my toolbar

Tags: android, icons, navigation-drawer, padding, toolbar

Does anyone know how to reduce the padding between de navigation icon and logo on a toolbar. for some reason it seems like there is way more space between them then between my logo and title.

I've already tried to add a style and use contentInset but none of them seem to work.

**My layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/background_grey"
android:style="@style/ToolbarTheme"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**My style**

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

[Image (Space indicated by red lines should be smaller)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOgXx.png)

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the Toolbar with the navigation icon and logo in which you are facing the issue.

Comment: @Karthik I've added a image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the gap between navigation icon and toolbar title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717684/how-to-reduce-the-gap-between-navigation-icon-and-toolbar-title)

Answer (score 16):

If you are interested only in *Reducing padding between navigation icon and logo on my toolbar*, use 
`Toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0)`

> Unlike `contentInsetStart`, this will modify the inset only when there
>   is a Navigation Icon. In the absence of the Navigation Icon, you will
>   still have the 16dp start inset.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` in  your toolbar xml.

Before adding `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` Output is:

[image]

After adding `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` Output is:

[image]
Hope its help.
Done

Comment: I have used the same `app:contentInsetStart="0dp` inside my `Toolbar` but it is not working.Please help me on it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha did you solved it? I too have the same issue and setting contentInsetStart to 0dp is not helping.

Comment: @Rahul Please refer this link , it can be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628064/3946958

Comment: @Ravindra Kushwaha, in my case the target layout was placed in a container that still had its own padding, so the setting had no effect.